# a given URL is the access location for the source files for the library

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

My task was to merge two videos together and play them one after another automatically.
This is the source code of my project
html code -

```js
var video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');

video.addEventListener('ended', function(event) {
  var currentVid = document.querySelector("#videoPlayer source.current");
  var nextVid = document.querySelector("#videoPlayer source.current + source") || document.querySelector("#videoPlayer source:first-child");

  currentVid.className = "";
  nextVid.className = "current";

  video.src = nextVid.src;
  video.play();
});
```

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" width="500" height="350" controls style="background:black">
        <source class="current" src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
```

My next task says https://videojs.com/ is the URL to access the source files for the library.
I am not getting what does this means?
Any idea?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a cdn where all css/js files are hosted on that link. Can you provide more details, so I can help! Thank you!

Comment: Yep, I was predicting the same because in the documentation it's written that video js is a video player. But how to upload my code there, that's the issue.

Comment: You don't need to upload your code. You can just include the video js cdn hosted files inside a simple HTML document, then load your video files as its written inside the documentation. You can display videos hosted on your web server or from external source. Include these:

Answer (score 0):

See https://videojs.com/getting-started/

You can get CDN hosted dist files at https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.19.2/video-js.css and https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.19.2/video.min.js, or install with NPM.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload your code. You can just include the video js cdn hosted files inside a simple HTML document, then load your video files as its written inside the documentation. You can display videos hosted on your web server or from external source. Include these: https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.19.2/video.min.js https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.19.2/video-js.css